# Create websocket connection between another server and a client

Tags: node.js, proxy, websocket

I'm building a desktop application where clients will interface with the server through the browser, but will also connect to eachother using a local node.js server. This means that every client has a local node.js server running.

I want to allow users to connect to the central webserver with the browser, and then initialize direct connections to other client's local node.js server. Is there a production ready way to expose a local node.js server to the outside world, or otherwise proxy the connection between the two?

Right now, my solution is to use localtunnel to expose the server, and then make a connection. As far as I understand, this is not recommended, and I'm looking for something better.

Comment: Which websocket module are you using?

Comment: "ws" https://github.com/einaros/ws